# Translating from English to FOL

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**Predicates**

$\text{drinks}(p)$: “Person $p$ drinks wine.”

$\text{single}(q)$: “Person $q$ is single.”

**English sentence**

“Single people drink wine.”

**Translations**

Which one of the two translations to FOL below is correct?

$\forall p (\text{single}(p) \rightarrow \text{drinks}(p))$, or  $\exists p (\text{single}(p) \wedge \text{drinks}(p))$

Comment: The second one means that there is at least one single person who drinks wine.

Comment: @MJD, so can I assume that there is an implicit "All" at the beginning of the English sentence? In other words, does the sentence "All single people drink wine" mean the same thing as "Single people drink wine"?

Comment: This question isn't really about FOL or quantifiers; it's about understanding an English sentence. It might be appropriate for the English Language Learners stackexchange site (or it might have already been answered there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition “Single people drink wine.” can also be written as “If a person is single, then it drinks wine.”. Therefore, for a person, say $p$, we have that $\text{single}(p) \rightarrow \text{drinks}(p)$. Note that this reasoning works with any person that we pick. I. e. we are not stating anything specific about some person (for that one would usually have some word regard existence in the proposition). So, $\forall p (\text{single}(p) \rightarrow \text{drinks}(p))$. To have $\exists p (\text{single}(p) \wedge \text{drink}(p))$, one should have “There is a single person who drinks.”.

Comment: Thank you. However, I believe you are slightly off when you say, “There is a single person who drinks”. Existence means there is at least one person, not just one.

Comment: When I said single person I was actually saying a person who is single

Comment: If you put it that way then it's correct. But I think the wording makes that sentence a bit vague; could be interpreted in many ways, both incorrectly and correctly. I would phrase it as "There is at least one single person who drinks wine" to be more precise.

Comment: @PeterChaula I agree, it was an unfortunate chose of words from me. My mistake. But that’s the idea.

Comment: "There is one blue ball... There exists one blue ball... There is a blue ball... There exists a blue ball" seem to fall on the <exactly one> to <at least one> spectrum in that order, even though they are arguably synonymous. Just putting in my 2 cents. @PeterChaula